# At the seder, does everybody make kiddush?

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada

Every year at the seder, we are not sure if everybody makes their own kiddush, or if the leader makes kiddush and everybody says Amen.

I was recently told by a friend that the custom at his seder is that everybody makes kiddush. Is this universal? And does it apply to all four cups?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13664/5

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate because here I'm asking specifically about the Seder.

Comment: That's why I wrote it with a question mark and didn't vote to close. However, I think it could be argued that this is a subset of that question. You are obviously assuming the answer to the other question is that it is preferable (or at the very least not negatively preferred) for everyone to make their own Kiddush and are wondering what to do at the Seder (though you fail to specify why the Seder would be different from any other night - LOL, I just thought that through but I don't intend to delete it!). Anyway, I think it's borderline.

Comment: Shi'a harav 472,21-22 says everyone should drink they're own wine, its not clear however if they should make the kiddush I.e. say the words themselves

Answer (score 4):

By Chabad the boys make their own Kiddush and the mother/girls listen to the father.

Comment: +1, but a source is appreciated.

Comment: Also, I don't know if this is correct. I know Lubavitcher families where everyone present, men, women and children, all say kiddush together.

Comment: @Alex, do you mean they recite it together, or do you mean they listen together to one person who recites it for everyone?

Comment: @SethJ: the former.

Comment: @MeirZirkind Boys under bar mitzvah make their own? (By the way, I wouldn't be surprised if they do make their own before/after being yotzei the father's. This is common in chabad, for chinuch)