# Which parts of the seder must be performed individually?

Tags: halacha, passover, passover-seder-hagada, motzi-yedei-chovato, hachnasat-orchim-guests

I have always wondered something about the Passover seder. Is the host being motzi everyone with his seder plate, or does everyone/every head of household* need to make a plate and personally carry out the entire seder? If not, what parts of the seder must be performed individually? (For example, those listed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70312/1516)? ... Karpas? Yachatz? Motzi matzah? Korech? ... Other parts?)

*I am also wondering if a husband would be motzi his wife and children over bar mitzvah, or if either of them would need to make their own seders.

Related: [At the seder, does everybody make kiddush?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15582/at-the-seder-does-everybody-make-kiddush?rq=1)

Comment: I'm confused what obligation you think the plate fulfills. Plates are just convenient places to keep food.

Comment: What parts of the seder are not performed by everyone in your experience? Yachatz? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: "I'm confused what obligation you think the plate fulfills. Plates are just convenient places to keep food." While that is surely true according to the _G'mara_, modern _hagados_ definitely refer to a _seder_ plate, and such a plate is so well known (by those who know about the _seder_) that I don't think it requires an explanation. Is there something you think can be improved w.r.t. the plate reference in this post? I think it is perfectly fine as is.

Comment: @DoubleAA I am just asking because there is often, at seders where I am a guest, a question of whether everyone makes his own seder plate. This year, I was told "the rabbi is doing it for everyone" or something to that effect and that I didn't need a plate. I didn't see any other guest making one, either. You are right that the plate itself is a separate question from whether each mitzvah needs to be done individually, but I think the issue is closely enough related to keep here.

Comment: @DoubleAA not a seder plate issue, but I have definitely heard of sedarim where only the leader washes before karpas.  If one isn't observant of washing for wet vegetables all year long, one person washing may well achieve whatever purpose this washing has (eg raising kids curiosity, symbolism with temple ritual & purity, etc).

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen So you are saying that if one doesn't have the custom (halacha?) to wash for wet vegetables, he should not do so at the seder table? And this other person's doing it on everyone's behalf will cover them all for the whole year? (Not questioning what you say; I simply don't get it)

Comment: @SAH If one doesn't wash for wet veg normally, he isn't washing at the seder for that presumably.  If he is washing so kids ask, won't they ask if one person does it too?  If it is symbolic of a return to the Temple & its rituals, couldn't one person washing do that?  I'm not saying that one person washing once covers everyone for every wet vegetable they eat all year long.

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen Oh OK ... maybe. Why would someone on principle not be makpid to wash during the year before wet vegetables? Although -- do we really ever eat them besides Pesach?

Comment: @SAH Pickles any time of year?

Comment: @Ze'evFelsen You win.

Comment: Also anything dipped in any other liquid any time of year