# Why ask guest to make kiddush?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, kiddush, social-convention

In my limited experiences in Baltimore and Lakewood, it seems hosts often ask guests if they would like to "make their own kiddush" with a separate cup of wine. Is there a reason why guests wouldn't want to be yotzei with Kiddush made by the host?

Comment: Reciting the kiddush at the Shabbos table is an honor. We tend to give guests honor, no? Guests in shul usually receive aliyos, etc.

Comment: It's a chassidish minhag for one to make their own kiddush. The host doesn't want to be presumptuous that their guest doesn't have this minhag. Also I know Baalei Teshuvah who took on that minhag even though they aren't externally chassidish. Could explain the Baltimore thing, as many BTs like to settle there.

Comment: I always thought it was because you want to make people comfortable, in case they don't want to rely on the *kavana* of the host acquitting them

Comment: AFAIK the [Chassidisher] Minhag is that the guest does it for his wife and kids, that it is preferable (debatable) for the husband and father to make Kidush rather than someone else. I remember making Kiddush for my wife for a couple of years after my marriage at my father-in-law's on Shabbos and festivals.

Comment: @Ezra That would apply here if the host asked the guest to make  kiddush for everyone there. In the OP's case the guest is offered to make his own, in addition to the kiddush the host will be making.

Comment: @ezra I take it you aren't a Kohein or a Levi. Getting an Aliyah is a hassle not an honor (at least since the institution of a Baal Keriah). Generally the regulars are sick of it so they pawn it off on to a guest. If any regular actually really wanted it he'd surely get priority treatment by the gabbi.

Comment: Politeness? (15 char...)

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm sad that this has been your experience

Comment: @ezra I'm sad you've gotten so used to seeing people say extra Berakhot and letting someone else do the work that you've forgotten what an irrelevant act they are doing. The Baal Keriah is teaching Torah. The Oleh is ensuring an obsolete choreography that can't yet be removed is maintained, and for the most part saying fundamentally unnecessary blessings that are only there lest someone leaves in the middle and gets confused about the procedure. Being trusted as a Baal Keriah is an honor. Saying pointless blessings because they used to split long portions among many Baalei Keria isnt

Comment: ( @ezra I'm also quite sad that that trivial act is the biggest contribution most Jews can make towards public prayer services, but that's more about the state of Jewish education today than anything else.)

Comment: @DoubleAA It was a little more than simply splitting long portions among many Ba’alei Keriah. *Minyan hakeruim* is an indicator of *kedushat hayom*.

Comment: @joelk chicken vs egg? would such an indicator have ever been designed if there was only one reader?

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair point

Comment: @DoubleAA I may not be fully appreciating the discussion here, but they divided Rosh Chodesh and fast day readings, which are quite decidedly _not_ "long portions", into several kerios, with sections of as little as 3/4 pesukim. It seems to me to be more of an a priori intention to split it, not just a convenience for baalei keria.

Comment: @yez your perspective of what a long portion is is skewed by using the annual cycle. In the triennial cycle 4 verses was probably a normal Aliya size (ave modern parsha verses ~100/7/3.5=4.1). Plus once they made this system of splitting they applied it to all days anyways; one particular short day doesn't show the system of making splits as a whole wasn't founded in a desire for reasonable portion sizes for readers

Comment: @DoubleAA I think that demonstrates the opposite - _no_ portions were long, and it was not for the convenience of baalei keriah that they divided it. Unless you are just asserting that baalei keriah in the times of Chazal were far, far less competent than your half-decent baal koreh of today?

Comment: @Yez indeed baalei keriah back then were average Joe's too in addition to rabbis, especially in smaller towns. You can tell me that an Aliyah is an honor because people think it is and honor is just a social construct, but you can't tell me that Chazal would have set up Torah reading the way we have it now as a way for multiple people to be standing in the middle of the room and that they would have intended for standing idly to be a a sought after religious experience. (And it can't be the blessings that are so exciting because originally most Olim didn't say any blessings!)

Comment: @DoubleAA Indeed, I cannot tell you what Chazal intended to be honorable experiences. Some of the things that Chazal considered to be honors are far beyond what I relate to. And I fully agree that honor, or honorable experiences, are social constructs, and public perception is a more significant factor in determining how to honor someone. But, as disparaging as one may want to be about the provenance of these _berachos_, after they are in place they are treated by _poskim_ as desirable _kibbudim_, not superfluous _berachos_.

Comment: @yez I didn't agree that honor is just a social construct, but if you think it is then please don't tell me I or anyone need to care what anyone else finds honorable, Poskim or not. If it's just what makes you feel good then you decide what makes you feel good. If leading morning brachot excites you, I hope the Gabbai gives you that and not Shlishi (or Shishi or Maftir or whatever you think is "most honorable" in your time and place, since these things change.)

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't at all follow what you are trying to show. Someone made an assertion that people receive _aliyos_ as honors. You said they are not honors and that in actuality "the regulars are sick of it so they pawn it off on to a guest." Now you are just denying that people feel what they feel, and really everyone deep down, despite paying money for _aliyos_ and having _halachos_ of who gets what as a _kibbud_, resents it and sees it as a burden which is just residual junk left over from a previous state? Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Yez I'm not denying people feel what they feel. We know there are rules for Darkei Shalom in case there's a fight (not fundamentally meaningful). And in the few cases of weddings and bar mitzvas most people still expect it. But overall it's not the case that nearly anyone cares. The original claim was we give Kibbudim to guests, but really guests are not high on the list at all and just the Gabbai says Oh Someone new, let's switch things up. If people cared the Gabbai would give members first, as he does on Yom Kippur. For most regular Shabbatot though no one cares at all. That's the Metziut.

Comment: @Doub So then I think we don't need to bother discussing any further if we just have experienced different realities. In your shul/community, perhaps that is the case. In _every_ community and Yeshiva that I have been in, that is not the case. The Gabbaim carefully measure who get _aliyos_ and make sure that they are generally distributed "fairly" among members _because_ everyone wants them, not because they want to evenly distribute the burden. Guests, and particularly honored guests and visiting scholars, are given _aliyos_ as honors. It's just a fact that this is the attitude in many places

Comment: @Yez [I'm sad that this has been your experience](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.21)

Answer (score 5):

The reason many prefer to make their own Kiddush rather than be *yotzei* from the host is because of the dictum מצוה בו יותר מבשלוחו - it is preferable to perform a Mitzvah personally [based on Kiddushin 41]. (Pri Megadim, MZ 207)

Others disagree, and claim that the above principle doesn't apply, because hearing Kiddush is better than regular שליחות, because שומע כעונה - it is considered as though he said it himself. (Tosefes Shabbos 273.10)

Many prefer to participate in the Kiddush of the host, because ברוב עם הדרת מלך - it is preferable to have more people participating in the Mitzvah than for each to perform it privately. (See Mishne Berura, 213.3)

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13664/759 Others may be trying to get towards 100 blessings if you hold Shomea Keoneh doesn't get you to 100 (which could explain why only males tend to do this, if you assume women aren't obligated in 100 blessings daily). Others could have a policy of doing so so as not to embarrass the people they don't trust to be Motzi them by only doing so at their houses.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I think the accepted psak is that Shomea Keoneh does work for Meah Brochos. I think it is only the Tehila Ledovid who says that it doesn't.

Comment: just saying there are other possibilities out there. And not everything accepted by you is accepted by others http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=1534&style=send

Comment: Perhaps relevant: there are times when some have the custom is to make one's own kiddush, such as at the Seder (to make blessings on each cup) and Simchas Torah (to make shehechiyahu personally on the Torah).

Comment: If Mitzva Bo Yoser mibishlucho surely all the men have already said Vayechulu Kiddush in Maariv, and why don't the women say kiddush?

Comment: @user15 because women used to be illiterate (and some communities today still pretend they are)

Comment: @doubleaa Even if they can't read they would have known Kiddush by heart throughout history as they are obligated mideoraisa and at some point in their life would say Kiddush for themselves e.g no men around so according to this answer women should say their own kiddush and men don't need to as they said it already

Comment: @user the fact is they didnt. you'd have thought they'd know how to bentch too and daven too, they're chayav in both, but the fact is they didn't know how, and the Rishonim all testify to that. The Magen Avraham worked very hard to defend the women from the obvious bittul asehs, inventing new opinions just Misvara. Its hard for us to comprehend how untrained and incapable those women were with no formal education. || Btw men didn't say Kiddush Al HaKos yet, and the women already said Maariv and Vayechulu even if not at shul so really they're all in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak for why most people who offer do so, or for why most people who accept accept, but I have a friend who both offers guests and accepts when offered as a guest because he has a short attention span, and doesn't want to rely on himself to pay attention to someone else for the entire *kiddush*. If he does it himself, he'll be better off. Lest a guest have a similarly short attention span, he offers guests. (I don't know if he offers or accepts Shabbos day *kiddush*, which one only needs to pay attention to about 4 seconds of, but maybe once you space out during the *pesukim* it's hard to keep track of when to space back in.)

Answer (score -1):

Shulchan Aruch 201,4

> צריך לחזור שיתנו לו כוס של ברכה לברך:
>   A person should go out of his way to be given his own cup of wine of a Mitzva to make his own blessing.

The source is from Nazir 66b the Shulchan Aruch paskens like Rav and Rav Huna that one should jump to say the Brocho himself rather than let someone else say the Brocho and say Amen:

> א"ל רב לחייא בריה חטוף ובריך וכן א"ל רב הונא לרבה בריה חטוף ובריך למימרא ד**מברך עדיף**

The Rosh explains clearly:

> חטוף כוס של ברכה **וכן כל ברכות**
>   Grab the oppurtunity to **make your own Brocho** (rather then say amein) **and this applies to all brochos**

**So when one has his own Cup of wine he should specifically not be Yotzi with someone else rather make his own brocho,**

---

{And Tosfos Pesachim 106a brings down a Minhag to give each person his own cup to make Kiddush which implies that Each person should ideally have his own cup of wine:

ירושלמי דברכות א"ר אבא בשם רב מסובין אסורין לטעום עד שיטעום המברך ר' יהושע בן לוי אומר שותין אע"פ שלא שתה ולא פליגי מה דא"ר אבהו כשהיו כולן זקוקין לכוס אחד מה דאמר ר' יהושע כשיש לכל אחד כוסו בידו ומשמע נמי אם אין כוסו בידו אפי' שפך מכוס ברכה לכוסות אחרים אין להם לטעום עד שיטעום המברך אבל כשיש לכל אחד כוס א"צ להמתין ולכך הוה גחין ושתי ומכאן יש להוכיח שא"צ לשפוך מכוס של ברכה לשאר כוסות ומיהו היכא דפגימי צריך לשפוך ממנו לשאר כוסות כדי שישתו כולם מכוס שאינו פגום
Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi says When each person is holding his own cup of wine while the host is making Kiddush they do not need to wait for the host to drink, rather each person can drink from his own cup straight away unless their cups are deficient in which case one must pour from the hosts cup into their cups (before the host drinks and his cup also becomes Pagum-deficient) Rabbi Aba says if there is only one cup available fro the host, one must not taste the hosts cup of wine before he has tasted it himself after having made Kiddush.

---

The Pri Megadim misquoted in another answer that Shomea ka-oneh means one should always do Kiddush oneself rather than be a listener. This does not apply with Kiddush on friday night before the meal Since men have said Kiddush in Amida, they have already fulfilled their obligation of making Kiddush themselves. So there absolutely no problem to listen to the baal habayis making Kiddush *again*.

Comment: Isn't this saying that when a group does a Mitzva together, you should try and lead? But no one their suggested breaking up the group to allow everyone to lead. אין מלך בלא עם. ברוב עם הדרת מלך.

Comment: That's not an accurate translation. It just says "one must go out of their way that they will give him the cup to bless on". There's only one cup. It just depends who gets it.

Comment: Your allowed to look at the edit

Comment: I'll be glad to now that you've included it. I see no indication in Tosfot that everyone had their own cup to say Kiddush. They had their own cup to drink, said Amen, and then drank without waiting for the Mevarekh to drink. It actually proves you wrong: if they all said Kiddush to themselves there'd be no discussion of if you have to wait or not.

Comment: but surelyonce they have their own cup of wine for the Mitzva  if they could make their own brocho it is a bigger Mitzva then saying Amein like The Shulchan Aruch says black and white

Comment: "How do we know it's better to say Kiddush by yourself then listen in a group? Because they had cups and obviously then they would say Kiddush rathe than listen!" Circular reasoning is circular reasoning. The biggest Mitzva is saying for a group, then comes listening in the group, then comes saying yourself. The Shulchan Arukh prefers 1 to 2. It doesn't discuss 2 vs 3. I told you this already above.

Comment: see Rosh that i edited in that explains like i said

Comment: no Rosh just says the rule applies outside of Bentching. I never disputed that.

Answer (score -2):

When different people (groups and families, usually) eat together, there are those who believe that the males (or head male) of each group should say kiddush for their group (or themselves) instead of relying on the host's recitation of kiddush. This is the reason why some hosts will offer their guests the opportunity to make kiddush on their own but then will proceed to make their own kiddush as well.

Source: Shulchan Aruch Harav, Orach Chaim 271:30

Comment: Shulchan Aruch Harav, Orach Chaim 271:30 doesn't say anything about what you said here. It discusses who drinks first: the one saying Kiddush or the ones listening.

Comment: There is 271:40

https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.30.1?lang=bi

Comment: I will try to  find one.

Comment: Your link is to the Kaf HaChayim, and also doesn't discuss the issue you wrote about

Comment: This answer is circular. The question was why would people believe that males of each group should say kiddush for their group. The OP knows this phenomenon exists