# Holding ones cup while someone is reciting Kiddush for you

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, shabbat, kiddush

I have seen many people holding their cup of wine while the host (or a chosen person) recites Kiddush for them. What is the explanation for holding ones cup?
Sources if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Shulchan Aruch ([Orach Chaim 183:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.183.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says that one should hold a cup of Blessing (e.g for Kiddush or Birkat Hamozon) in his right hand.

> כשמתחיל לברך נוטלו בימינו

[Tosfos in Pesachim 106a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.106a.9?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Pesachim.106a.9.1&lang2=bi) brings in the name of Yerushalmi Brochos that when available, each person is given his own cup of wine which he holds in his hand during the recital of Kiddush by the head of the household:

> ירושלמי דברכות א"ר אבא בשם רב מסובין אסורין לטעום עד שיטעום המברך ר' יהושע בן לוי אומר **שותין אע"פ שלא שתה** ולא פליגי מה דא"ר אבא כשהיו כולן זקוקין לכוס אחד מה דאמר ר' יהושע **כשיש לכל אחד כוסו בידו** ומשמע נמי אם אין כוסו בידו אפי' שפך מכוס ברכה לכוסות אחרים אין להם לטעום עד שיטעום המברך אבל כשיש לכל אחד כוס א"צ להמתין ולכך הוה גחין ושתי ומכאן יש להוכיח שא"צ לשפוך מכוס של ברכה לשאר כוסות ומיהו היכא דפגימי צריך לשפוך ממנו לשאר כוסות כדי שישתו כולם מכוס שאינו פגום ...
>
> Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi says When each person is holding his own cup of wine while the host is making Kiddush they do not need to wait for the host to drink, rather each person can drink from his own cup straight away unless their cups are deficient in which case one must pour from the hosts cup into their cups (before the host drinks and his cup also becomes Pagum-deficient) Rabbi Aba says if there is only one cup available in the hand of the host, one must not taste the hosts cup of wine before he has tasted it himself after he has made Kiddush.

Comment: Is that Yerushalmi not talking about where each is making Kiddush for themselves on their own cup??

Comment: @doubleaa if they all made their own Kidush individually then why would we need Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi to tell me that they can drink before the host of course they should drink straight away otherwise it would be a hephsek so they should ignore the host. The whole Yerushalmi is mechadesh that even though _only_ the Host made his own Brocho the others can still drink before him provided they are holding their own cups

Comment: Then why'd you argue the opposite at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96408/759

Comment: @doubleaa the Yerushalmi is saying a Haacha that one _can_ rely on the Hosts Brocho and drink ones own cup straight away that he is holding in his hand. In the answer quoted i am stating that from the Bavli Nozir 66a it would be better for each individual to bless themselves on their own cup as _Chatof uvoreich_